# How to extract data from multiple XML's into a table using AWK

Tags: xml, bash, awk

I have multiple XML files in one directory, and i would like to extract different types of data from it into a one, table-like output (tabs between the fields).
Also, i would like to have headers (column names), and a boolean interpolation in some of the columns.

I have prepared 2 sample XML files that can be found below, and i would like to have a AWK command that will run through all of the files in that directory, and extract the following values:

1. The file's name
2. The value of "property1" (numeric)
3. The value of "property2" (boolean)
4. The string "$test1$"
5. The string "$test2$", if exists

   - In the real directory i have more than 200 files and i would like all of them to be represented in the output, even if some of them don't have any of the above values.
   - Note that the values "$test1$" and "$test2$" are under a different parent element. The "property1" and "property2" elements (#2 and #3 in the list above) will always stay the same, but not necessarily in the same order  (as shown in my input files below).
   - I know how to get to the desired output with the file's name and one of the other values from the list above (using the FILENAME built in parameter in AWK), however i cannot seem to add additional values properly.
   - To my knowledge, AWK is the best tool to use for such a thing, but if you think of another tool that will provide the same output, then i'm more than ok with it :-)

Please find below both the XML files (the input data):

TextXML1.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestXML1>
    <properties>
        <property name="property1" value="500"></property>
        <property name="property2" value="true"></property>
    </properties>
    <attrs>
        <attr type='parameter' name='T1234'>
            <parameter input='$test1$'></parameter>
        </attr>
        <attr type='parameter' name='H5H7'>
            <parameter input='$test2$'></parameter>
        </attr>
    </attrs>
</TestXML1>
```

TestXML2.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestXML2>
    <properties>
        <property name="property2" value="False"></property>
        <property name="property1" value="300"></property>
    </properties>
    <attrs>
        <attr type='parameter' name='TD837'>
            <parameter input='$test1$'></parameter>
        </attr>
        <attr type='parameter' name='JQE284'>
            <parameter input='$test3$'></parameter>
        </attr>
    </attrs>
</TestXML2>
```

And the desired output:

```
    File name   property1   property2   $test1$     $test2$
TestXML1.xml   500      True        True        True
TestXML2.xml   300      True        True        False
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `awk` is in general a bad tool for parsing xml (because XML isn't actually line based, and two equivalent XML files could be formatted very differently).  In most cases you are better off using something that can actually parse XML (like Python, or Perl, or Ruby, or ...). Also, when asking "how would I write this" type of questions, we generally expect you to show us what you've tried yourself, first.

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: Please include the XML in-line in the question.

Comment: @Cyrus - thank you, however i am not familiar with xmllint and xmlstarlet. If there is a way of doing it using awk and/or sed and/or grep that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Kusalananda- i have attached the input files and desired output text to the question body. I apologize, but this is the first question i ask here :-)

Comment: @EdMorton- i have changed both the question body and the sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to extract all the names, values and inputs using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/\<name="([^"]*)".*\<value="([^"]*)"/,a) { n2v[a[1]][ARGIND] = a[2] }
match($0,/\<input=\047([^\047]*)\047/,a) { inputs[a[1]][ARGIND] }
END{
    printf "Filename"
    for (name in n2v) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, name
    }
    for (input in inputs) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, input
    }
    print ""

    for (fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGC; fileNr++) {
        printf "%s", ARGV[fileNr]
        for (name in n2v) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, (fileNr in n2v[name] ? n2v[name][fileNr] : "N/A")
        }
        for (input in inputs) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, (fileNr in inputs[input] ? "True" : "False")
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk TestXML1.xml TestXML2.xml
Filename property1 property2 $test1$ $test2$ $test3$
TestXML1.xml 500 true True True False
TestXML2.xml 300 false True False True
```

You can easily tweak it to only select the ones you care about.

Answer (score 0):

As various others have already pointed out, you should not use line-oriented tools like `awk` to process XML. Use an XML-aware tool like `xmlstarlet` instead. Here's a partial solution to your problem:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v //property/@value -nl -v //parameter/@input -nl TestXML1.xml TestXML2.xml
```